# Use i2p or freenet in command line

Tags: wget, tor, i2p

Is it possible to use i2p in command line (like `torify` for tor)?

I'm looking for a way to use `wget` with i2p or freenet networks, something like:

```
i2p wget www.myurl.com
```

instead of:

```
torify wget www.myurl.com
```

thanx.

Answer (score 2):

use [i2pd](https://github.com/PurpleI2P/i2pd) instead. but you must run i2pd (yes, from command line) first and then you can:

`http_proxy=127.0.0.1:4444 wget 102chan.i2p`

Comment: Wow, thanx, i didn't now about the daemon, i'll have a look :)